# How do I get totals grouped by one column?

Tags: sql, count

I have a table with three columns (apart from the id):

- topic
- user
- ip

`Topic` cannot be null, but the other two can. There are no unique restrictions.

So an example of data would be this:

[image]

What I want to get is the distinct combination of `user` and `ip`, and count the resulting rows grouped by topic:

[image]

## EDIT:

Ok, the first popular answer is:

```
SELECT topic, COUNT(IP)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY topic;
```

But I see you are ignoring the user column, why? Maybe my example was not good :)

Let's add a new record:

[image]

Running the above query would give us the same result, but it is wrong:

```
SELECT DISTINCT topic, user, ip FROM MyTable;
```

It returns:

[image]

So in this case the totals would be:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Topic, COUNT(*) [Count]
FROM table
WHERE IP IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Topic
```

Sample:

```
-- preparing the data
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (Topic int, [User] int, IP varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
(1,1,null),
(1,1,null),
(1,1,null),
(1,null,'127.0.0.1'),
(1,null,'127.0.0.1'),
(2,1,null),
(2,null,'127.0.0.1'),
(2,null,'127.0.0.1');

-- getting the resuls
SELECT Topic, COUNT(*) [Count]
FROM @tbl
WHERE IP IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Topic
```

### For the edited question:

```
;WITH TMP AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT topic, [user], ip
    FROM @tbl
) 
SELECT Topic, COUNT(*)
FROM TMP
GROUP BY Topic
```

Comment: If you exclude NULL, you won't get the counts of 2 and 2 for each of the two topics, so this won't match the desired output.  I think Abe has it right

Comment: it will be the same, I will attach sample you can copy, paste and run to see that the result will be the same. Actually, Abe answer is pretty the same. he exclude null too, using the COUNT(ip) and I did it a bit more explicitly.

Comment: The result is the same, but I see this approach as an over-complication. It's not wrong, though.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT topic, COUNT(IP)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY topic
```

Answer (score 0):

For the result you expect, this is the query:

```
select topic, count(ip)
from YourTable
group by topic
```

Note that `COUNT` only counts non-null values.

**Update**

After your edition and further clarification, you can do this:

```
select topic, count(*)
from (SELECT DISTINCT topic, user, ip FROM YourTable) sel
group by topic
```

or this:

```
select topic, count(distinct cast(ip as varchar) + '#' + cast(user as varchar))
from YourTable
group by topic
```

in this second method, the query may have to vary according to your RDBMS (which you did not specify). Data types might change, as well as the concatenation operator/function. The concept behind it is that you cannot have `DISTINCT` within `COUNT` with 2 different columns, so you have to concatenate them. The `#` character is just to make sure `1#11` is different from `11#1`.

Answer (score -1):

not sure if you can do this

```
select  topic, count(COALESCE(topic,'null') + COALESCE(ip,'null')) from table
group by COALESCE(topic,'null') + COALESCE(ip,'null')
```